# Scrapy crawl Multiple XPathSelector on same page

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, scrapy

Im trying to extract data from different 'tables' inside a 'Main Table' on the same page (Same URL). The items fields have the same XPath / same structure in all sub-tables, so the problem I am facing is just to **add 'Multiple' XPath for the tables sections on this page**.

Here what my code looks like :

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name = "test"
allowed_domains = ["blabla.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.blablabl..com"] // Start_url Doesnt change = Same Page



def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = [hxs.select('//tr[@class="index class_tr group-6487"]')]

    //Here I would like to have Mltiple XPathSelectors ex:

    // titles = [hxs.select('//tr[@class="index class_tr group-6488"]')]
    // titles = [hxs.select('//tr[@class="index class_tr group-6489"]')]

    // Each for a table section within the same 'Main Table'



    items = []
    for title in titles:
        item = TutorialItem()
        item ['name'] = title.select('td[3]/span/a/text()').extract()
        item ['encryption'] = title.select('td[5]/text()').extract()
        item ['compression'] = title.select('td[8]/text()').extract()
        item ['resolution'] = title.select('td[7]/span/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

I would appreciate any hint if this is achievable; If I write a different spider for each table section, then I will end up with 10 spiders for the same URL/table and I am not quite sure if data could be retrieved within the same 'csv' file in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
titles = [hxs.select('//tr[@class="index class_tr group-6487"] | //tr[@class="index class_tr group-6488"] | //tr[@class="index class_tr group-6489"]')]
```